# Save image into file generated by FileProvider

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I save image into file generated by FileProvider? I have method called `getImageUri` that returns `Uri` of file in specified path. I want to append bytes of `Bitmap` into that file and I'm getting error that says the path/file doesn't exists. What could be a problem here?

FileProvider:

```
class ComposeFileProvider : FileProvider(R.xml.filepaths) {
companion object {
    fun getImageUri(context: Context): Uri {
        val directory = File(context.cacheDir, "images")
        directory.mkdirs()
        val file = File.createTempFile(
            "selected_image_",
            ".jpg",
            directory,
        )
        val authority = context.packageName + ".fileprovider"
        return getUriForFile(
            context,
            authority,
            file,
        )
    }
}
}
```

And here is code how I am trying to write bytes inside generated `Uri`

```
val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
val decoder = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.contentResolver, it)
val imageBitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(decoder)

imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)

val uri = ComposeFileProvider.getImageUri(context)

File("com.myapp.test.fileprovider", uri.path)
    .appendBytes(outputStream.toByteArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple of things here:

1)A URI from a file provider isn't a file (it may be, but it doesn't have to be).  In any case it's inappropriate to try to open it as a file.

2)Even if it is a file, and you have permission to write it, your root folder you're using is totally wrong.  com.myapp.test.fileprovider isn't a folder.  It's a classname, which is meaningless in that parameter.

3)Why are you using a FileProvider here at all?  FileProvider is for when you want to provide access to a file to another activity.  If you're the only app involved here, just use the filename, no URIs or providers.

4)You wouldn't write a bitmap like that anyway.  If the file isn't empty, appending the file stream would corrupt it.  If the file is empty, just use Bitmap.compress and pass it an output stream that goes to that file to write it directly to that file.  Calling outputStream.toByteArray is almost always a mistake.

Comment: I want the application to keep images even when user delete it from gallery

Comment: So you're making a copy of images from the gallery.  That's fine, but there's no reason to involve you writing a FileProvider to do that.

Comment: Yeah, basically I want to make copy of that photos to app storage. Do you have better idea how I can do it?